# Tar incremental restore : Cannot rename

Tags: backup, tar

I created a python script to do an incremental backup strategy on seven days whith a full backup on Sunday, using the command : tar

I have no probleme to generate my differents backups.
However, I've got an issue during trying to restore an incremental backup with this message error :

```
tar: Cannot rename `./path1' to `./path2': No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

My backups strategy run for a jenkins service.

Do you why I've got this error message which stop my restore. And do you know how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: **DO NOT use** GNU's `tar` for **incremental** backups.

The long answer is, - there is pretty old bug that won't allows to restore incremental archives reliably. The bug still exists and reported multiple times since 2004.

---

*References:*

[stackexchange 01](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411324/is-it-possible-to-use-tar-for-full-system-backups/451834#451834),[stackexchange 02](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463898/tar-potential-bug-when-incremental-archive-selected-deleting-files-in-the),

[Ubuntu-Lunchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/freezer/+bug/1570304),

[GNU 01](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-tar/2008-07/msg00005.html), [GNU 02](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-tar/2016-07/msg00025.html), [GNU 03](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-tar/2016-07/msg00026.html),

[Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=648048)